# How do you mention an account or channel in a YouTube comment?

Tags: youtube

Almost all online platforms and instant messaging applications, Telegram, Twitter, Facebook, Instagram allow to mention another account within their platform, typically by preceding the account name by the "@" symbol.

How do you do the same thing - mentioning other YouTube accounts/channels - in a YouTube comment?

Comment: Bad news is you can't. At least not anymore. Previously youtube allowed commenting account names using +. This has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **October 2022**, you can do that by using `@username` format tagging on channel pages, in Shorts, and in comments. See [this YouTube News and Events page](https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/introducing-handles-a-new-way-to-identify-your-youtube-channel/).

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, tagging on YouTube is not possible anymore. The only way to still tag someone in a legit way is to hit “reply”.

Comment: It's not even possible by "hackig" the html, http or ajax system, there is a safety mechanism to prevent you from doing it. Big bummer. (Or at least I haven't figured it out yet after 1 hour fiddling.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Faraz's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125741/55949):

If the person you want to refer to has a Youtube *Channel*, you can edit in the URL of the channel (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1of9ELYwB623fWaAMRDVFA). This will not 'ping' that person (2nd party), but for 3rd parties it that makes  it clear who you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

@marcolackovic,

@faraza is correct. You can no longer mention or tag someone on a[youtube-channel](/questions/tagged/youtube-channel)if you decide to reply directly in the main comments section.

---

### Alternative Solution:

The following is someone’s comment thread:

[image: *Source*: How to Tag Someone in a YouTube Comment (https://apkafe.com/how-to-tag-in-youtube-comment/)]

As you can see, if you reply to the main comment, the tagging feature is not available.

---

> **I have a workaround...** You can still tag someone on [YouTube](https://youtube.com), but *only if you click `REPLY` to them in a comment thread.*

---

---

Here is how to tag someone in a Youtube reply to a comment...
[image: https://apkafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/image-3.png]

You can now see what happens when you click `reply` to someone in the comment thread. It will automatically tag the user in the comment you are writing.

---

---

Now, post a comment and see what happens to the tag. 
[image: https://apkafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/image-4.png]

You will see that after posting the comment with an auto-tag, the username is tagged in the post and appears blue. That’s how to tag someone on YouTube. 
[image: https://apkafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/image-5.png]

---

Hopefully, this gives everyone some more clarity as well as an inside tip/trick alternative if you want to tag or mention someone in the video comments in spite of [YouTube](https://youtube.com) not having a direct way to mention or tag others.

---

[Source](https://apkafe.com/how-to-tag-in-youtube-comment/) | [Author Email](https://apkafe.com@gmail.com)

[youtube-channel](/questions/tagged/youtube-channel) [youtube](/questions/tagged/youtube) [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) [youtube-new](/questions/tagged/youtube-new)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the reply to a "main comment" will not tag, but only to a lower level one.